# When treating deadly wounds, what do I add my WIS modifier to exactly?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, healing

The [heal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/heal#TOC-Treat-Deadly-Wounds-) skill states:

> Treating deadly wounds heals 1 point of damage per level of creature being treated. If you exceed the DC by 5 add your WIS modifier (if positive) to that amount.

Adding my WIS mod to "that amount" is vague in my opinion. The only "that amount" previously discussed is 1 point per level of creature. If that's the case then when I treat someone of level 3 and I have a WIS mod of 4 then a heal check will heal for 15 pts of damage. (1 + WIS = 5 × 3 levels of creature = 15) I assume that isn't the case and instead it's adding WIS mod to total making it 7 pts. (1 × level = 3 + WIS = 7)

Can someone provide an example of how treat deadly wounds should work and clarification of the rule?

Answer (score 6):

The amount of damage that would be healed by not exceeding the DC by 5 would be 1 per level (3 in your example).
Had you beat the DC by 5, "that" amount would be increased by your wisdom modifier (again, 3+4=7 in your example).